# RunAsDate: Change DateTime for spawned process

Tags: windows, process, date-time

Using RunAsDate, it's possible to change a DateTime for a single process.
However, when this process spawns another process, for example by interacting with a DLL or another .exe, the other process of course doesn't inherit the changed DateTime from the "main" process.

Is there a way to change their DateTime as well?

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt this is possible with RunAsDate. Processes do not inherit the date and time of the parent process but obtain this information by using the system functions. Windows does not provide a direct method of changing this behavior. RunAsDate works by intercepting the functions normally used to obtain time and date information and substituting what you have provided. RunAsDate cannot do this for any spawned processes because it would have no knowledge of them and in any event is no longer running.

Comment: Could I solve it with a symbolic link to the spawned file so that Windows would load the RunAsDate'd file instead of the real file?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you know the name of the process(es) that will be launched in advance, then you can setup the "Image file execution options" debugger value.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mithuns/2010/03/24/image-file-execution-options-ifeo/ for more info.

Comment: @tmighty: You may be able to run RunAsDate that way but how would you tell it the real program it is to run and the date it is to use?

Comment: @LMiller7 Can you be more specific? I don't understand your comment. Thank you.

Comment: RunAsDate changes the date on a process it starts. It does not change the date on any processes it may spawn. It was not designed to do so. I think you should rethink your problem and devise a solution that does not require this.